# How to resolve "argument of type 'boolean' is not assignable..."

Tags: javascript, reactjs, typescript, jestjs

I've an input component and I'd like to create unit tests for it. I'm having few errors and I can't fix it. I already see in few blogs, but I don't understand how to resolve it. I'm trying to improve my knowledge in unit tests, but it's complicated.

Here's my code I put into [codesandbox](https://codesandbox.io/s/stoic-panna-7u2b9w?file=/src/App.tsx):

[image]

I don't understand why I've this error, because I don't have any Boolean parameter. How can I resolve it?

```js
import React from 'react';
import { render, screen } from '@testing-library/react';
import TextInput from './TextInput';
import { TextInputProps } from 'src/types';

describe('Text Input', function () {
  it('should render default', function () {
    const props: TextInputProps = {
      change(): void {},
      value: '',
      placeholder: 'Full Name',
      variant: 'neutral',
    };

    render(<TextInput {...props} />);
    expect(screen.getByRole('textbox')).toBeInTheDocument();
    expect(screen.getByRole('textbox')).toHaveAttribute(
      'placeholder',
      'Full Name'
    );
    expect(screen.getByRole('textbox')).toHaveAttribute('value', '');
  });
});
```

```js
import React from 'react';
import { TextInputProps } from 'src/types';
import './index.scss';

const TextInput = ({
  value,
  placeholder,
  type = 'text',
  variant,
  change,
}: TextInputProps) => {
  const inputVariant = `input-field ${
    variant === 'highlight' ? 'highlight' : ''
  }`;

  return (
    <div className="content-input">
      <input
        className={inputVariant}
        value={value}
        placeholder={placeholder}
        type={type}
        onChange={change}
      />
    </div>
  );
};

export default TextInput;
```

```js
import { ChangeEventHandler } from 'react';

export interface TextInputProps {
  value: string;
  placeholder: string;
  type?: 'text' | 'password' | 'email';
  variant: 'neutral' | 'highlight';
  change: ChangeEventHandler<HTMLInputElement>;
}
```

Comment: Please review *[Why not upload images of code/errors when asking a question?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/285551/)* (e.g., *"Images should only be used to illustrate problems that* ***can't be made clear in any other way,*** *such as to provide screenshots of a user interface."*) and [do the right thing](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/76358648/edit). Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use a .tsx file, not a .ts one.

On the example you sent, I was able to reproduce the error, then noticed you were using a .ts file. Rename it to .tsx and the error is gone.